# Data bound Datagridview cell return value is wrong

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a `datagridview` cell which is databound. 
I am trying to save the previous value of the cell using cell begin edit event.
When i try to save this cell information, it saves the  value member field value instead of the text whihc is in the `combobox`.
The code I use is :

```
stroldvalue = DGVTransactions.CurrentCell.Value
```

Is there a way to store the text of the cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()`, you can get the text with:

```
DGVTransactions.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue
```